# Получение выбранного элемента JList (Java)

Tags: java, swing

Есть вот такая панель JList :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы в зависимости от выбранного элемента из JList в JPanel отражался какой-либо текст.

И если пользователь нажал на любой другой элемент, то появлялся другой текст.

Слышал что-то про getSelectedValue() , но куда вставить не знаю.

Не могли бы вы помочь мне с реализацией такого метода?

Comment: не обязательно справа должна быть JPanel, можно даже JText)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен обработчик события выбора элемента списка:

```
jList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
        if (!evt.getValueIsAdjusting()) { // Игнорируем событие mouseDown
            // Получаем выбранное значение
            String val = jList.getSelectedValue().toString();
            // Устанавливаем полученное значение в текстовое поле
            jTextArea.setText(val);
        }
    }
});
```